# Bloquear fechas pasadas y futuras en DateRangePicker

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

Tengo una consulta, tengo un código para abrir un DateRangePicker, pero quiero bloquear días pasados, para eso yo usaba `startDate: '-1d'`, pero últimamente no me bloquea las fechas pasadas en el calendario, saben qué estoy haciendo mal para que no me funcione?

```
$('.daterange-single').daterangepicker({
            singleDatePicker: true,
            locale: {
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                startDate: '-1d',
                daysOfWeek: ["Dom","Lun","Mar","Mie","Jue","Vie","Sáb",],
                monthNames: ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"
                ],
                firstDay: 1
            },
        });
```

A la vez, también saber si existe:

- ¿Cómo bloquear fechas futuras? Ya que quiero lograr en mi calendario si hoy es 05-05-2021, me muestre habilitado desde el 04-05-2021 y 05-05-2021.
- Existe la posibilidad de bloquear sábado, domingos y feriados?

Answer (score 2):

Por alguna razón cada vez que añado el daterangepicker a las librerías en stackoverflow, me da error. En fin debes usar `isInvalidDate` esta recibe una función que evalúa tu rango de fechas seleccionadas y te dice si es válida o no, así podrías deshabilitar los fines de semana. Y más sencillo aún, [hacer algo como en este ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/21hdLtf7/)

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="05/01/2021 - 05/15/2021" />


$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left',
    minDate: "04/30/2021",
    maxDate: "05/15/2021",
    isInvalidDate: function(date) {
      if (date.day() == 0 || date.day() == 6){
        return true;
      }
    
        return false;
    }
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
});
```

Como notarás se usa las propiedades `minDate` y `maxDate` para decir nuestro valor de fechas permitidas. Ya si quieres hacerlo dinámico pues solo usas las funcionalidades de momentjs o de Date de javascript